# Error al publicar sitio web MVC .NetCore 6 con VisualStudio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, runtime

Buen día.

Espero puedan ayudarme con lo siguiente.

Tengo un sitio web desarrollado en MVC NetCore 6 y VisualStdio 2022 pero al momento de publicarlo en el servidor me manda el siguiente error al ingresar a la ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otros sitios en el mismpo servidor y funcionan correctamente solo que está creados con NetCore 5 en Visual 2019, ya he consultado las versiones de sdk y runtimes y están las correctas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que otra configuración hace falta, es el primer proyecto que publico de NetCore 6 con VS 2022.

de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

intenta publicar de nuevo pero con esta opción seleccionada, en general esto permite que eliminar archivos que están demás y utiliza las versiones más nuevas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no funciona y estás en un ambiente controlado, podrías habilitar la página de excepciones para el desarrollador.

Por acá te dejo más información.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0